In ASP.NET Core Web API utilizing EF Core, how can you add/update children only?
I want to insert a Topic that has parent Course. I send the CourseId, but it is telling me the Course field is required.
public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; } = null;
    public int? TopicId { get; set; }
    public virtual Topic ParentTopic { get; set; } = null;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<Topic> SubTopics { get; set; } = new List<Topic>();
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; } = new List<Question>();
}



I was hoping that marking the parent entities as 'virtual' would do the trick, but it does not.

Try changing the type of the property from Course to Course? (nullable course). When you make it a nullable property, you are making it explicit that it is optional. Apply the same change to the ParentTopic property.

Please show the actual code that throws the exception.

@julealgon I should have thought of that.  It took 2 minutes to try and solved the problem.  You should make it an answer.  The answer.

When the "nullable reference types" feature is enabled for your project, always make sure to use nullable references to represent optional relationships and values.
Change the type of your optional relationships as follows:

Course -> Course?
ParentTopic -> ParentTopic?

And they should now be treated as optional by EFCore and validation.
Alternatively, if you chose to, you could also disable the nullable reference types feature in the project by setting the Nullable MSBuild property to disable (or just removing the property, as it defaults to disabled if missing). More details here.
Context:
When nullable reference types started getting adopted by frameworks like AspNetCore, EFCore, etc, the libraries started to consider a nullable reference as "optional", and a non-nullable one as "required". This used to require dedicated attributes in case of reference types (such as [Required] from data annotations). Now the design has been "unified", behaving similarly both for value and reference types.
